# what is the benefit of using *{margin:0;padding:0}?

Tags: css

I have seen CSS definitions like this:

```
* {margin:0;padding:0};
```

What is the benefit of using this and what kind of problem we can avoid by using it?

Comment: "what kind of problem we can avoid" - you know, non-zero margin and padding. :)

Comment: Do you know what the `*` does?

Comment: As an aside, `*` can be heavy on the rendering engine: http://css-tricks.com/margin-0-padding-0-no-longer-cool/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

thats just a very [basic css-reset](http://www.cssreset.com/). there are some better (but more complex) solutions to normalize css for all browsers, one of the most known and used is [the eric meyer reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/), for example.

> A CSS Reset (or “Reset CSS”) is a short, often compressed (minified) set of CSS rules that resets the styling of all HTML elements to a consistent baseline.
>
> In case you didn’t know, every browser has its own default ‘user agent’ stylesheet, that it uses to make unstyled websites appear more legible. For example, most browsers by default make links blue and visited links purple, give tables a certain amount of border and padding, apply variable font-sizes to H1, H2, H3 etc. and a certain amount of padding to almost everything. Ever wondered why Submit buttons look different in every browser?
>
> Obviously this creates a certain amount of headaches for CSS authors, who can’t work out how to make their websites look the same in every browser. (NB: article coming soon about why this is a false notion!)
>
> Using a CSS Reset, CSS authors can force every browser to have all its styles reset to null, thus avoiding cross-browser differences as much as possible.

Comment: you're welcome. please remember to mark this post as answer by clicking the tick-mark to the left of it if your question is solved.